# Gradle multi project transitive dependency

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-dependencies

I have three `gradle` projects. Say `ProjectA`, `ProjectB` and `ProjectC`.

`ProjectC` is dependent on both `ProjectA` and `ProjectB`. While `ProjectB` is dependent on `ProjectA`.

So `ProjectC`'s `build.gradle` has the following lines:

```
dependencies {
  implementation project(':ProjectA')
  implementation project(':ProjectB')
}
```

And `ProjectB`'s `build.gradle` has the following:

```
dependencies {
  implementation project(':ProjectA')
}
```

My question is why do I need explicit `implementation` declaration for `ProjectA` in `ProjectC`'s build file?

Since, I am adding `ProjectB`, shouldn't `ProjectA` be included automatically since `ProjectB` is dependent on `ProjectA` ?

In other words, why the following does not work for `ProjectC` ?

```
dependencies {
  implementation project(':ProjectB')
}
```

I am new to `gradle` and thus trying to understand how dependency management between Project's work.

---

Edit:

So I want to change `ProjectB`'s build.gradle to below:

```
dependencies {
  api project(':ProjectA')
}
```

So that I can simplify `ProjectC`'s build.gradle to:

```
dependencies {
  implementation project(':ProjectB')
}
```

However, I get the following error:

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':ProjectB'.
> Could not find method api() for arguments [:ProjectA] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Because `implementation` is precisely for that: it tells that ProjectA is needed for the code of ProjectB to work (internally), but is not part of its API (i.e. you don't want clients of ProjectB to rely on the fact that it uses ProjectA internally).

If you want ProjectA to be part of the API of ProjectB, then use the `api` configuration rather than `implementation`.

See [the guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_separation) for more details.

Comment: thanks. That helped. does gradle have "testApi" as well like "testCompile" and "testImplementation" ?

Comment: Read the guide I linked to, and you'll know.

Comment: I read the guide. And tried to do what I have described in the Edit section. However, I am getting the error mentioned.

Comment: You need to apply the java-library plugin.

Comment: this info is a bit obsolete: @Deprecated(message = "The apiElements configuration has been deprecated for dependency declaration. Please use the 'implementation' or 'compileOnly' configuration instead.")

Answer (score 9):

Add

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
}
```

to the parent project `build.gradle` file, this will enable `api` modifier for the project, which tries to use it.

See:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html